# run eclipse/che local image on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes-helm, eclipse-che

I would like to run the eclipse/che image that i built in my PC.

Step 1: I built che based on the instructions: https://github.com/eclipse/che/wiki/Development-Workflow.
`mvn clean install` to create the image under `assembly-main/target` folder as a tar file.

Step 2: tried running the image on kuernetes using:
`$ helm upgrade --install che --namespace che --set cheImage=eclipse/che-server:7.0.0-beta-4.0 --set global.cheWorkspacesNamespace="che" --set global.ingressDomain=${CHE_DOMAIN}.nip.io ./`

... as shown here: https://che.eclipse.org/running-eclipse-che-on-kubernetes-using-docker-desktop-for-mac-5d972ed511e1

I believe that the above command pulls the image from public image registry (is it docker hub?). I would like to use the image that i built using step #1 shown above.
Please let me know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

After successfully running `mvn clean install` you can build the docker image using `dockerfiles/che/build.sh` like this: 
`dockerfiles/che/build.sh --organization:myorg --tag:mytag --dockerfile:Dockerfile`

This should build image `myorg/che-server:mytag`. Then you can push this image to any docker registry you are using in your k8s cluster and use it in the helm chart.

Comment: Thank you, i shall try this.